# start (vpn) service from AndroidViewModel

Tags: android, android-intent, mvvm, android-service, android-viewmodel

My searches did not return an answer, but one or two unanswered questions. I'll try to phrase it in a way that maybe I get an answer.

**TL;DR version:**

I cannot figure our how it is possible to launch a (VPN) service from AndroidViewModel class.

**Longer version:**

Normally, from an activity I would launch a service like this:

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = VpnService.prepare(this);
        if (intent != null) {
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
        } else {
            onActivityResult(0, RESULT_OK, null);
        }
    }
```

Obviously, in MVVM I want to pass on the click event to the AndroidViewModel (or simply ViewModel, but I need Context, so AndroidViewModel it has to be), and there I want to launch the service.

Am I supposed to do it like this? It seems messy.

```
public void startStopButtonWasClicked(WeakReference<Activity> MainActivity) {

    //do other stuff

    Intent intent = VpnService.prepare(MainActivity.get());
    if (intent != null) {
        application.startActivity (intent, 0);
        MainActivity.get().startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
    } else {
        MainActivity.get().onActivityResult(0, RESULT_OK, null);
    }

}
```

Or should I implement onActivityResult in the VM class?

Edit: this is not even possible: `MainActivity.get().onActivityResult(0, RESULT_OK, null);`

Answer (score 0):

You don't navigate from your viewmodel, you navigate from your view/controller, send a command to your controller saying you want to start a service and start it from your controller.
By the way getting your activity context like this : `MainActivity.get()` is really bad, never put a activity context in a static member.

> Or should I implement onActivityResult in the VM class?

Indeed when you get your result from your controller you can send it to your viewmodel to handle it

Comment: Sorry, but it is not entirely clean for me. Activity should be used as a View, and not a Control in MVVM. If this is the case, why would I launch a background service, which has no visual effect in the View - from the View?! (On the other hand, as long as it is weakreference and it is "got" by .get(), that should not be the problem either - although I don't like the "cleanliness" of it either. Or am I wrong?

Comment: MVVM doesn't meen no controller, your activity is still a controller and the right place to navigate between activities or fragments, viewmodel is to handle data not to navigate, but you may still start a service from an application context using `AndroidViewModel` if you want